# ASCII code equivalent of unicode character in Java

Tags: java, c++, unicode, localization, ascii

We have a problem in porting following logic from C++ to Java. The Java method should return same value as the C++ function. The logic fails if, keyValue contains non-ASCII characters.

The C++ function goes as below,

```
   int CMyClass::KeyToId( const char *keyValue ) {

    int sum = 0, len = strlen( keyValue );

       // Get a sum based on the characters in the string.
       // Each character contributes + <ASCII-value> * 11.
       for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )   sum += keyValue[i] * 11;
       // Modulo the result to get a value in the standard range.
       return sum;  
   }
```

In line #2, keyValue[i] is converted to a 8 byte ascii code.

The exact port to Java looks like below:

```
private int keyToId(String keyValue) {
     int sum = 0, len =  keyValue.length();

        // Get a sum based on the characters in the string.
        // Each character contributes + <ASCII-value> * 11.

        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )   
            sum += keyValue.charAt(i) * 11;
    return sum;
}
```

In Java, the character keyValue.charAt(i) is converted to the "unicode" value. I couldn't figure out a simple way to convert this into equivalent ASCII code. The C++ app is a non-unicode application. Please presume, we cannot change the C++ logic.

More inputs:
I'm running the apps in Russian language. For a input of красный, the C++ app returns -1452. I'd like to get the same value from the Java code.

Comment: If you are running on Windows, with codepage 1251, the string красный should be encoded as [-22, -16, -32, -15, -19, -5, -23] and the C++ code you have shown should compute -1452. You can verify that by hand. If it really returns -300 the code must do something more than you have shown.

Comment: The result depends on the encoding, UTF-8 would give another result. The main problem is the faulty assumption that ASCII (an **American** Standard) covers Russian.

Comment: @Joni -1452 is the correct result. I excluded some code before sharing, but forgot to recalculate the result.

Comment: "In Java, the character keyValue.charAt(i) is converted to the "unicode" value." No, it returns the UTF-16 code unit value, which will be the same as the Unicode code point value only if the Unicode code point is in the range [U+0000, U+FFFF]. If the UTF-16 code unit value is in the range [U+D800, U+DCFF] then you've got a surrogate code point and the actual Unicode code point value is in the range [U+10000, U+10FFFF] and does not fit in a Java 2-byte `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ program uses the platform's default encoding to represent characters in the `char` data type. To do the same in Java you have to use Java's equivalent `byte` data type, and convert the string before the computation:

```
byte[] bytes = keyValue.getBytes();
for (byte b: bytes) sum += 11*b;
```

If that doesn't work either,

- Check the sign of `char` in your C++ program: most compilers use signed chars by default, which coincides with Java's byte. If you use unsigned chars the code needs an adjustment.
- Check that the Java program is reading the string correctly to begin with. One way to do that is print the bytes; given `красный` you should get `[-22, -16, -32, -15, -19, -5, -23]`:

  ```
  System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(bytes));
  ```

Comment: It's signed in this case too, else you wouldn't get a result of -300.

Comment: Ok, your second point gives some clues. I get this in the bytes array: [63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63]. I'm checking it..

Comment: Does this text come from a file? Probably the program is not reading the file correctly. ASCII 63 is the question mark, it's  used as a replacement for characters that cannot be represented in the destination encoding.

Comment: I was testing with this text passed from Eclipse -> Debug -> Arguments. It somehow corrupted the text midway

Answer (score 1):

Try to truncate Java chars to 1 byte

```
 sum += (0xFF & keyValue.charAt(i)) * 11;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Charset.forName("US-ASCII").encode(keyValue).toArray()`

Gives you a `byte[]` array of ASCII code and afterwards you can operate same as in C++.

Comment: did you mean the array() method of ByteBuffer. Sorry that didn't work.